# Transfer and extract message by Audio signal in Android

Tags: android, audio, signal-processing, javasound, audio-processing

I do research about audio processing and have a big problem to solve. Is it possible to transfer a text message or binary stream(10101010) by embedding it into audio signal, broadcasting it so that other android devices can record that sound and extract text message or binary stream which was embedded?

Comment: This is possible, and was solved uncounted times by various espionage agencies.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind your audio signal being plainly detectable, then this is what an acoustic modem does, and there's tons of modulation schemes, software protocols and modem implementations described in the amateur radio and telephony literature, including RTTY, AFSK, PSK-31, Bell-103, and etc., some decades mature and well tested on noisy radio bands and bad phone lines.

Answer (score 0):

Field is EXTREMELY complicated, try googling for [Audio Steganography](https://www.google.com/search?q=audio%20steganography&aq=0&oq=audio%20stegano).

You'll have to know exact properties of the medium that will carry your signal.

You'll have to analyze sound in real-time on both sides, searching for places to put your bits.

You'll have to avoid all compression and audio losses in the sending->receiving chain.

...

And in the end, you'll at best get few BITS/SECOND if you are lucky.  However, consider that you'll be unable to send ANYTHING if the sound is, for example, silence.

ALTERNATIVELY: try with **audio watermarking**, maybe that's what you need, in fact.